# backbone.js view return false

Tags: backbone.js

can somebody explain me, for what is in a backbone.js view the return false statement. For example

```
search: function() {
  var view = this;
  $.post('/contacts/find',
    this.$('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    view.render(data);
  }).error(function(){
    $("#results").text('No contacts found.');
    $("#results").slideDown();
  });
  return false;
},
```

Comment: can you make sure variable data is correct

Answer (score 2):

To cancel default event behaviour.
In your example after clicking the submit button the form will not be submitted (page reload).
This is the same as:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: it mean, when i submitted the form and then click page reload, it will avoid to submit again?

Comment: No, it means when you press "submit" button the page will not be reloaded http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: as usual, when submit clicked, the page will be reload automatically?